# Add domain to hyperlinks after .load function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to change the (internal) hyperlinks of loaded content into external (by adding a domain to the href) but something isn't working correct or loaded in the right order...

This is what I've tried so far.

First I created a php page *loadingmodels.php*, with only this in it:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Then I load the external content in my content div:

```
$(function(){
    var contentURI= 'https://somepage #model-selector';
    $('#content').load('loadingmodels.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
```

This loades data like this in my content div:

```
<div class="model-selector" id="model-selector">
      <div class="car-row">
            <div class="car-item item1" data-id="20">
                <a href="/link1" class="btn-car-more">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="image.png" alt="Name1">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="model-name">Name1</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="car-item item2" data-id="3">
                <a href="/link2" class="btn-car-more">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="image.png" alt="Name2">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="model-name">Name2</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Finally, and this I can't get to work, I would like add a domain the the internal hyperlinks; ie, change "/link1" into "https://someotherpage/link1".

This is what i tried (placed underneath the above code):

```
$(function(){
    $("a.btn-car-more").each(
        function() {
            href = $(this).attr('href');
            new_href = 'https://someotherpage' + href;
            $(this).attr('href', new_href);
        }
    );
});
```

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `load()` call is asynchronous. Therefore you're trying to amend the `.btn-car-more` links *before* they exist in the DOM.

To fix this you need to run your logic in the callback of the `load()` method, to ensure that the HTML has been injected in to the DOM first. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var contentURI = 'https://somepage #model-selector';
  $('#content').load('loadingmodels.php?url=' + contentURI, function() {
    $('a.btn-car-more[href^="/"]').attr('href', function(i, href) {
      return 'https://someotherpage' + href;
    });
  });
});
```

There's a couple of things to note in the example above. Firstly I used the 'attribute begins with' selector to only target the `href` attributes which are relative to the original path. Secondly, you can avoid the explicit `each()` loop by passing a function to `attr()` this function will be executed on each Element in the collection.